# How do I ask the Vision API to apply multiple features on an image

Tags: google-cloud-vision

How do I call the Vision API and apply more than one feature on an image.
I want to apply both Label Detection and the landmark detection on an image

Answer (score 2):

You can define your request as below to incorporate multiple feature requests per image

```
    "requests":[
    {
      "image":{
        "content":"/9j/7QBEUGhvdG9zaG9...image contents...fXNWzvDEeYxxxzj/Coa6Bax//Z"
      },
      "features":[
        {
          "type":"FACE_DETECTION",
          "maxResults":10
        },
        {
          "type":"LABEL_DETECTION",
          "maxResults":10
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: how you would you send it to the server ?

Answer (score 1):

```
from google.cloud import vision
import os 

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/path/client.json"

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
response = client.annotate_image({
      'image': {'source': {'image_uri': 'gs://yourbuket/1.jpg'}},
      'features': [{'type': vision.enums.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION},
      {'type': vision.enums.Feature.Type.FACE_DETECTION}],
    })
```